# Format multiple lines within {} argument say example \ifbool

Tags: formatting

Ok as a follow up to last ask, how do I format multiple commands inside a {} parenthesis so that it doesn't crash, throw an error?  thanks

example

\ifbool{@switch}{???????????}{???????}

this works:

Example: doofus.sty

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{doofus}%
[2014/01/01 v0.01a LaTeX doofus package]%\filedate\space\fileversion\space 
\typeout{Package doofus, \csname ver@doofus.sty\endcsname%
^^ Copyright (C) 2014 ^^J}

\RequirePackage{calc}
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}[2006/11/18]
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newbool{@epubstate}
\boolfalse{@epubstate}
\DeclareOption{epub}{\booltrue{@epubstate}}
\ProcessOptions%

\ifbool{@epubstate}{\newcommand{\doofus}{\textcolor{black}{7\spadesuit}}
\newcommand{\doofustwo}{\textcolor{black}{6\spadesuit}}}
{\newcommand{\doofus}{\textcolor{red}{7\heartsuit}}\newcommand{\doofustwo}{\textcolor{red}}{6\heartsuit}}}
```

but i need to put 50 lines in each ifthen {}.  How do I make sure it's syntacticly correct?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether I understand your question correctly:

> How do I make sure it's syntacticly correct?

If I did, I think your problem can be solved with two approaches, which I both strongly recommend:

1. Use indentation:

   ```
   \ifbool{@epubstate}{
       \newcommand{\doofus}{\textcolor{black}{7\spadesuit}}
       \newcommand{\doofustwo}{\textcolor{black}{6\spadesuit}}
   }{
       \newcommand{\doofus}{\textcolor{red}{7\heartsuit}
       \newcommand{\doofustwo}{\textcolor{red}}{6\heartsuit}}
       %% ... 48 commands more
   }
   ```

   This is already well-readable.
2. Use an editor that supports syntax highlighting and colors the corresponding opening brace when the cursor is at a closing brace. Possible editors are `vim`, `kile`, `emacs` and many, many others.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_%28programming_languages%29

Comment: In computer science, the syntax of a computer language is the set of rules that defines the combinations of symbols that are considered to be a correctly structured document or fragment in that language. This applies both to programming languages, where the document represents source code, and markup languages, where the document represents data. The syntax of a language defines its surface form.[1]

Comment: @daemondave: what do you want to say with that comment? And why is it a comment to my answer and not to the question?

Comment: i did answer your question, I am looking for the right syntax. It seems you were unclear what syntax meant. Read it and that will explain what I was talking about.

Comment: @deamondave I know what syntax is, but I was not sure whether this really was the point of your question, because you had another question in your post ("... so that it doesn't crash, throw an error?"). Now, does my answer answer your question?

Comment: I used indented commands as recommended in gedit, but crashes latex with error:  

! LaTeX Error: Unknown option `epub' for package `poker'.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.356 \ifbool
             {@epubstate}{
? H
The option `epub' was not declared in package `poker', perhaps you
misspelled its name. Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
? X

Comment: the irony is, if you would allow one to put in a file with more than 30000 chars I could show you the complete code, but alas I have to do it by half measures.

Comment: Try adding `%` after each line inside the `\ifbool`

Comment: To post many chars you can try [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/)... But nobody will read 30k lines of code anyway

Comment: % after each line, interesting what does that do for syntax? I will try...

Comment: didn't work.... still came up with errors...